# How to do not update attributes of an entry if such value is null jpa

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, annotations

I'm updating an entry in my database and for this I created an object with **only the fields I want to update.**

My problem is that the empty fields are being replaced in the database as well. So non-null values in the database are replaced by null when I just wanted to ignore those null values.

I ve tried to use @DynamicUpdate annotation in my @Entity but it does not work since it still replaces those non-null values with null as they have different values.

Here is my code so far:

```
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
@Table(name = "Exer")
public class Exer implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String nome;
    private String grupo;
    private String path;
}
```

In Controller:

```
Exer exer = new Exer();
exer.setId(4);
exer.setNome("value");
exerDao.update(exer);
```

Dao implementation of update:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

@Transactional
public Exer update(Exer exer) {
    return em.merge(exer);
}
```

In this case I just want to change Nome to "value" and instead I'm inserting null for the other two fields of this entry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not how you update with JPA. You first get the existing entity from DB, for example EM.find(Exer.class,KEY), then you set the fields you want to update, commit transaction and that is. JPA will update only the fields that has been changed.

```
em.getTransaction().begin();//or skip if transaction is managed by controler
Exer exer = em.find(Exer.class,4);
exer.setNome("value");
em.getTransaction().commit(); //skip if transaction is managed
```

Comment: To be honest with you, I thought about doing this at first.. but then I was wondering if there was another "more elegant" way.. but thanks! this way I'm pretty sure it will work :)

Comment: I was a little bit worried about the performance of this as well, since we need to do two queries to do something we could easily do with only one query if we wrote the raw SQL statement

Comment: Chances are that the object will be already in JPA context so it could be only one query. If you discover at some point that those 2 queries impact your application performance you can always refactory it and call sql manually. But I am sure the other parts of your system will be bottleneck not the jpa queries.

Comment: yes, you are right.. I ended up using this approach, it shouldn't have any serious performance prob :)